# Installing Ubuntu on hybrid hard drive system i.e. HDD+SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a system upgrade recently and added 256GB SSD on my PC and now I want to install Ubuntu on dual-boot alongside Windows 10 but there is a problem I can't Understand what partitions should I make and on which drive as I can give 90GB of SSD space to Ubuntu and 400GB of HDD.

I am thinking about creating `/` partition on SSD and `/home` partition on HDD but I am confused that if normally creating both partitions on two separate free space on two drives as we do to install Ubuntu normally.

Comment: It's the same way as with a single drive. It really doesn't matter where the partitions are, you choose "something else..." And then edit the partitions as you wish.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please [edit] your question and add the output of the command `parted --list`, leave a comment @Fabby and then we'll be able to guide you.